# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7, I Can only boot ubuntu through recovery mode

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, windows-7, recovery-mode

I want to become a new user of Ubuntu, however this problem is preventing me.

I have/had Window 7 professional on my computer. I recently looked into getting linux. I discovered dual-booting and decided to give it a try.

First I created a bootable flash drive with ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. I then followed the instructions on:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

after I finished going through the setup, my computer rebooted.

After the reboot I was able to select Ubuntu, advanced options for Ubuntu, 2 memory tests, and windows 7 (loader).

So I chose Windows ( honestly i was more concerned that i still had everything on windows at this point). I then rebooted again and selected Ubuntu. When i selected Ubuntu, the background screen of Grub (the crimson/burgandy color) stayed for a few seconds then the screen went black:

video here>>>

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kKcG4sT7Lg&feature=plcp

  I tried again with the same results. so i redid the ubuntu install differently using
- http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/dual-booting-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/.

After rebooting the same thing happened. After that i was stumped, so i figured it could hurt to experiment. after all i backed up my windows 7 stuff, and i have the software disk.

I tried booting in recovery mode under "advanced options for Ubuntu" and sure enough, after selecting continue to normal reboot it worked.

So i updated and everything but when i rebooted it still wouldn't boot under Ubuntu. It would always boot after recovery mode. So i try installing 12.10 32 bit Ubuntu. the same problem keeps happening. I can still get to Ubuntu through recovery mode. so i went online and tried using the terminal (in ubuntu that i booted through recovery mode) when i was using it i discovered that "Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:

```
EOFError: EOF read where not expected" kept showing up. also i noticed a notification in the top right corner that looked like a do not enter sign. it said "an error occured, please run package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. the error message was: 'ror in sitecustomize;set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
traceback (most recent called last): File "/usr/bin/lsb_release
EOFError: EOF read where not expected 39;0' this usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies"
```

Naturally i assumed this was what was causing my boot problems. I downloaded synaptic and updated everything and the error went away. but my boot problem was still a problem. so i go online find some things that have worked for others, like this>

Try to do this (in your terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it too :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

And update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should fix stuff.)

I did this and i still have the problem.
sorry for the excessive explanation,

please help.

Comment: i can only have 2 hyper links in my question the first one is   <https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot>

Answer (score 0):

1. Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) --> Advanced Options --> GRUB options --> tick `Uncomment GFXMODE` --> Apply
2. Write on a paper the URL (http://paste.xxxxxx) that will appear.
3. Reboot the PC. If any problem, please indicate the URL.

Answer (score -2):

la mejor opcion seria que en vez de hacer particiones hubieras instalado con wubi, la unica limitante es que solo puedes darle 30gb de espacio a ubuntu :/ , instala la de 32 bits aunque tu proceasador sea amd de 64 , es mejor la de 32, ahora mismo la estoy instalando desde wubi, te ahorras la particionada y es mas sencillo al momento de instalar, reinstalar y formatear.

Comment: Please post in English.

Comment: ok but my english  is bad xD

you should install ubuntu in windows(typing in google wubi) ,
you should download ubuntu 32bits(no 64 NO!! NOOOOOOO!! ),
and be happy :D